# Ubuntu One and mounted drives

Tags: ubuntu-one, nfs

I'm trying to get my music onto Ubuntu One so I can keep it synced, but I'm having a problem.

My music is on my NAS (running on a Linux Server), it's mounted in my home directory.

I can set the directory as synchronised, however none of the files get synced.  If I move them into a standard folder on the system they do sync though.

Is this a problem with Ubuntu One or is it a limitation?

Comment: Wow ! that really IS a limitation !
The developer's have forgotten that many of use have partitioned drives.
I have a boot partition and a Data partition. I've just tried a symlink, but the Ubuntu One client decided it was an external or network share, so it blocked me. This is worse behaviour than Dropbox, so unless i can tweak the config file it looks like bye-bye ubuntu one. ps, its not hard to develop a sync system that can work out if an entire device has dropped off the system. (Team Dropbox seem to have managed it, but i guess that's why they're one of the market leaders).

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation. Currently, we don't support syncing from folders outside your home directory.

The main reason is that Ubuntu One does synchronization. If you synced a removable device, and then uplugged it, it would see all the files disappear, and also remove all its contents from the website and all your other devices.

Comment: my question was more that it is mounted inside the home directory, and I've read questions on here that said that providing it's mounted inside the home directory then it would pick it up.  Is there no way to do this? without being able to sync my music collection on my NAS, it's kind of pointless for me.  I can understand from a "documents" point of view, but for Music it doesn't make sense.